# How to output valid lat-long GeoJSON from WKB using django.gis.geos.GEOSGeomety?

Tags: django, leaflet, geometry, coordinates, geos

I have a database that has geometry attributes in the WKB format:

`010400000001000000010100000035553113AC38F64062B44D0A97951A41`

I am using `django.gis.geos GEOSGeometry` in order to get the MultiPoint coordinates:

```
    goem = "010400000001000000010100000035553113AC38F64062B44D0A97951A41"
    x = GEOSGeometry(geom)
    print(x.json) //output { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 91018.754685719337431, 435557.760062044602819 ] ] }
```

I also have a flyto map function that works with latitude and longitude but does not work with the format presented above:

```
        //working version
        latitude = 51.91648
        longitude = 4.45246

        map.flyTo([latitude, longitude], 11.5, {
            animate: false,
            duration: 0 // in seconds
          });

        //not working version. How is possible to translate these 2 coordinates in latitude and longitude
//        coordinateA = 91018.754685719337431
//        coordinateB = 435557.760062044602819
//
//        map.flyTo([coordinateA, coordinateB], 11.5, {
//            animate: false,
//            duration: 0 // in seconds
//          });
```

Is there any way to compute the latitude and longitude based on the coordinates that come out of GEOSGeometry?

Comment: I smell a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Where is the data ultimately coming from (filesystem, API, database), and what coordinate system is that using?

Comment: The data comes from a local postgres database. It uses geometry (in the example above, `010400000001000000010100000035553113AC38F64062B44D0A97951A41` is the geometry value of the 6th row of the database, where a row has the following fields: gid, schooltype, province, street, housenumber, postcode, city, municipality, `geom`, which is of type `geometry`)

Comment: So the issue here is that GeoJSON requires the data to be in the EPSG:4326 CRS (as per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-4 ), but the source data in PostGIS is in other CRS (do see https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html ). It's possible to reproject from one CRS to another: (a) Once doing an `UPDATE` in PostGIS; (b) every time data is`SELECT`ed in PostGIS; (c) Every time `django.gis.GEOS` loads a geometry; or (d) every time a web browser loads a geometry by leveraging `proj4js` and/or `proj4leaflet`. Optimal solution should be (a) **if** you can change the PostGIS data.

Comment: Oh and get yourself familiar with https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs . Seeing something more readable than WKB when doing SQL will help you.